# segmentation fault when assign returned pointer to variable

Tags: c, pointers

I've got the following code

```
char * find(struct node *r,char *str)
  {
      r=head;

     if(r==NULL)
     {
        return NULL;
     }

    while(r!=NULL)
   { 
       if((strcmp(str,r->name) == 0))
         {
           printf("found %s\n",r->name);
           char *p = malloc(256);
           strcpy(p,(const char *)r->name);
           return p;
         }
      r=r->next;

   }

  return NULL;

 }
```

and in the `main`：

```
void main () 
  {
    ......
    ......
    char *ret;
    ret = find(n,"someone");
    printf("%s\n",ret);
    .......
 }
```

with the above piece  of code, I've always got segmentation fault. but when I do away with the `ret` variable. it works.

```
void main () 
{
   ......
   ......
   printf("%s\n",find(n,"someone"));
   .......
}
```

Comment: `char * find(struct node *r,char *str)
  {
      r=head;`
What is the point of giving `r` to your function if your first line is assigning to `r` something that's not even in the parameters?

Comment: Why are you always allocating 256 bytes? You *know* the exact length of the string (you do know about the `strlen` function?) and so can allocate the exact amount. Also, most platforms have a `strdup` function. And why not simply return `r->name` (or even `str`)?

Comment: i've tried removing that but the program will not work as expected. i don't know why

Comment: Use a debugger to find out which line of code is causing the segmentation fault. You are getting lots of good suggestions but I suggest you'll benefit more if you try to find the cause yourself rather than someone solving it for you.

Answer (score 7):

There are many issues (logical and programmatic) in your code. For example,

1. You accept `r` as a parameter, but immediately replace it with `head`. Why use as a parameter then?
2. Before `strcmp()` , you didn't check for `NULL` in `r->name`.
3. You did not check  the success of `malloc()` before using the returned pointer.
4. In case `find()` returns NULL, using the return value in `printf()` will cause [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Now, the segmentation fault is *one of the side effects* of undefined behaviour. Correct the above issues first to make your code stable.

Note: Along with this, it's worthy to mention, the proper signature for `main()` is `int main(void)`.

Comment: without the parameter, it doesn't work as expected!also, if i use the function directly in printf, it works, but not assigned to a pointer variable

Comment: Doesn't mean it's the right thing to do. If you don't understand why it's needed, then chances are you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @benson Just because something works sometimes, doesn't mean it's correct. That's the problem with [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), sometimes it can *seem* to work.

Answer (score 0):

You check `NULL` on `r`, but not on `str` and `name`.

Comment: `next` **is** checked by the while